# Python-Mockito 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing unit tests with mockito, and have a function with one particular line that is causing me trouble:

```
score_data = json.loads(hdfs_client.read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(score_path).strip())
```

I have tried to different ways of mocking this:

```
when(mock_hdfs_client).read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(any()).thenReturn(score_cache_entry)
```

and

```
doReturn(score_cache_entry).when(self.mock_hdfs_client).read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(any())
```

where 'score_cache_entry' is a json-like string.

When running the unit test, I am being thrown this Attribute Error:

```
    score_data = json.loads(hdfs_client.read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(score_path).strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
when(mock_hdfs_client).read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(any()).thenReturn(score_cache_entry)
```

`any()` might be the python builtin.  If you're on python 3 try the Ellipsis form instead:

```
when(mock_hdfs_client).read_txt_from_hdfs_with_pipe(...).thenReturn(score_cache_entry)
```